# How to define media query at MaterialApp level, so that it could be applied to all screens/scaffold in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

In my **web enabled** flutter app, To add media query I have added `css` class in `body` tag in index.html file.

```
<head>
    ....
    <style>
      .mobile{
        max-width:auto;
      }
      @media (min-width: 600px) {
        .mobile{
           max-width:400px;
        }
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="mobile">
   <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

But flutter here is creating `flt-glass-pane` tag inside the `body` tag and it is rendering UI overflowing the `body` tag.

In my second approach, I have to add MediaQuery at screen level, but I don't want to add media query in each `scaffold/screen`.

So is there any alternative so that I could apply media query in `MateriaApp` or in `index.html` file only once.

Comment: Have you already considered using `LayoutBuilder` widget as child of `MaterialApp` widget. This brings in the available size information as constraints using which you could adapt your ui.

Answer (score 0):

Use "builder" in Material App

```
MaterialApp(
 ...
 ...
 builder: (context, child) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Center(
             child: Container(
                      width: screenWidth > 600 ? 400 : screenWidth,
                      child: child,
                    ),
           );
      }, 
);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and It's working but only with the `Center` or `Align` widget, and adding left elevation to the `child`.